# Swig c++/c# keep getting "Type Initialized Exception"

Tags: c#, c++, swig, quantlib-swig

I am currently creating my first swig project. I have some c++ code, where i am using 1 of the classes functions in my c# UI. I have created a .i file that looks something like this:

```
%module mymodule
%{
    #include "Simulation.h"
%}

/*****************************************************************************
 *                            SOME DEFINITIONS                               *
 *****************************************************************************/

#define EXAMPLE_DEFINITION 'a'
#define EXAMPLE_DEFINITION_2 'x'


class Simulation
{
public:
    // BUNCH OF FUNCTIONS
    static unsigned int getTick();
    static void tick();
// BUNCH MORE FUNCTIONS
private:
    // A BUNCH MORE THINGS
};
```

I added the cs files using:

```
swig -c++ -csharp -outdir UI -o cpp/simulation_wrap.cpp Simulation.i
```

It produces several files, which i add to my c# project. in my code if i add the lines:

```
Simulation.getTick();
```

or

```
Simulation.tick();
```

I get no compile errors, but the following run time error:

```
The type initializer for 'mymodulePINVOKE' threw an exception.
```

have I missed out any steps? I have tried searching for this but haven't managed to get any success.

(Perhaps it is important to note that i have tried compiling the c++ as a dll and a lib).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd save yourself a lot of trouble if you just use managed c++ to invoke Quantlib and compile into an assembly.  You need to compile as a DLL thats for sure.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to:

1. add ####.cxx to c++ project and rebuild to get a new dll(maybe you need to correct some error)
2. Copy that new dll file to [C#]\bin\x86\Debug (Release).
3. Go to Build->Configuration Manager. For the C# project change AnyCpu to x86 and rebuild.

   [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764160/not-able-to-run-swig-c-sharp-examples-in-vs-2010)