# How can I make LAMMPS into a Unity native-plugin?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, lammps, unity3d-native-plugins

**Context:**
I have been tasked with creating an interactive molecular dynamics simulation in Unity. The library I have been instructed to use is LAMMPS, which is based in C++. I have been looking at solutions for using C++ libraries within Unity by creating dlls to interact with C#, but it seems that when I try to follow the same steps with LAMMPS I run into errors. I find the [LAMMPS documentation](https://guriang.unpad.ac.id/lammpsdoc/Build_link.html) on this topic a bit confusing & not very beginner friendly.

**Problem:**
How do I make LAMMPS compatible with Unity? LAMMPS is a huge library, and I'm not sure how to go about making it usable with C#. For example, [this tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/integrating-native-c-c-libraries-with-unity-as-plugins-a-step-by-step-guide-17ad70c2e3b4) shows creating a dll with a header and source file, but it is only using the functions within those files. The LAMMPS docs say that library.h/cpp are the interface files, so if I go in and adjust those alone, should that be enough to be able to create a dll?

I am working from the LAMMPS source code on Windows in Visual Studio.

**Note:** Please excuse my ignorance on this topic, I have never worked with LAMMPS or bringing any sort of external library into Unity before. If anyone could help walk me through the steps to use LAMMPS as a native plugin within Unity, I would really appreciate it. Any guidance will be heavily appreciated, and I'll do my best to respond to questions/feedback as quickly as I can. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You didn't mention the errors you ran into while trying to adapt the library into a Unity plugin. That tutorial does explain the basic steps but for a large and complex library you'll definitely run into other issues you'll need to solve. You might look into the SWIG interface option and see if that helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534054/how-can-i-include-swig-wrapped-c-in-unity-3d